# Is there a way to make JSdocs to generate a documentation without any declaration of a new object or function?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

So I'm trying to generate a simple doc with jsdoc for a line in my code, but jsdoc is ignoring it because I'm not declaring anything. Is there a way to force it?
This is what I'm trying to do:

```js
/**
 * Just trying to doc something like this
 */

JSONLogic.add_operation('sqrt', Math.sqrt);
```

I tried to add a `@todo` tag, but it didn't work either.

Comment: The example isn't a function that needs definition? It's an expression that calls a function

Comment: That is right.. It calls a function but the function is not my to declare, it's a JSONLogic function, and yet, I want to doc it in my code

Answer (score 0):

I use apidoc package to document my code like function, api and...
You can visit [apidoc package](https://apidocjs.com/) to provide documentation for your code: like function, api,..

This is a piece of code that I wrote inside my project and used this package:

```
/**
 * convert georgia dateTime to persian dateTime
 * with custom format.
 * @param inputDate you should pass dateTime value for convert.
 * @param format When pass inputDate, sync format of dateTime with this argument.
 * @returns {string}
 */
function convertPersianCalender(inputDate, format) {
    if (inputDate) {
        let date = moment(inputDate)
            .locale("fa")
            .format(format);
        return date;
    }
}
```

after wrote like that, when you want use this fucntion in another file, Tells you intelligently what this function wants and what it gives, and you can also get a documented output by executing the command.

Comment: Please consider adding a [mcve] to your answer? Short answers with a link are not very helpful, especially if the link breaks. -- Also, suggesting the OP use a completely different documentation tool is not helpful either.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks... Do you know if it will work in the example I posted above? For detecting any line as something to be documented?

Comment: @MichaelSperling what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: A definition of what this function call did, in this example - Just trying to doc something like this. I want this to be doced to html file like jsdoc is doing with anything that you declare

Comment: I put a piece of code from my project. and if you run command of this package, generate html doc for you

Comment: Yes I see. This is also the behaviour of jsdocs. But in my case I'm not declaring the function so it doesn't doc it for me, but I still want some documentation.. In your case you define the function so it is all right. Maybe it is just not possible to doc something you didn't declare..